# Node Rotation In SceneKit SceneKitRotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, rotation, scenekit

I have just jumped in to using scene kit for iOS for the first time. What I am trying to do is import a .dae file, and rotate the object in code. What is happening is that when I import my file, I see that it is oriented the way I would expect.
[image: Imgur]

This is great, now I want to rotate it so that the longer end goes horizontally. With my coordinate system this should be a 90 degree rotation around the Z axis. Doing that in the graphical part of xcode shows this.
[image: After rotation]

The problem comes in when I start to manipulate this in code. If I undo the rotation in the graphical interface and try to perform it in code I get unexpected behavior.

If I start with no code changes, the simulator shows this
[image: Imgur]

If I perform a code rotation around the Z axis with this code

```
// create a new scene
SCNScene *scene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"art.scnassets/board.dae"];
SCNNode *board = [scene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"board" recursively:NO];
board.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 0, 1, M_PI/2);
```

I do not see the expected behavior in the simulator, I get this
[image: Imgur]
Which does not show much detail but the board has been rotated around the Vertical axis, which I thought would be the Y axis. This led me to try and rotate around the Y axis for kicks and grins. Here is the code for that.

```
// create a new scene
SCNScene *scene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"art.scnassets/board.dae"];
SCNNode *board = [scene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"board" recursively:NO];
board.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, M_PI/2);
```

This yields the following, which is what I want.
[image: Imgur]

Now for the real question, why do I have to rotate around a different axis in code? In this instance I was able to make it work, but in others like my camera, I can not. I think there must be some sort of coordinate shift that I am missing once something goes to code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have not personally worked with SceneKit, but the way you describe it, sounds like it's just the frame of reference that changed. Perhaps, in Xcode you are looking at a face which is different from the one you see on your device/simulator. Try marking the faces (put a dot or something) and see if that's the case, for a hack-y solution to your problem. I'm sure someone more experienced with SceneKit will come up with a more complete answer soon.

Comment: Your Collada file is probably using the "Z_UP" convention. 
If so, loading the scene with "sceneNamed" (with no option) will not convert your scene to "Y_UP". 
Xcode probably forces the Y_UP conversion. You can do the same programmatically if you need by passing YES to the "SCNSceneSourceConvertToYUpKey" option when loading a file. What if you save the file with Xcode? does it change your collada to Y_UP?

Comment: I think this is correct, I will verify.

Comment: This was in fact correct. I use blender for building my models and they all Z_UP. After knowing this I was able to figure out my rotation issues. If you answer with this comment I'll mark it and put more detail.