# Camera Rotation in SceneKit

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, rotation, scenekit

I have posted a similar question to this
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859597/node-rotation-in-scenekit-scenekitrotation) , but this is different in that it deals with eular angles.

Given the setup that I had in the other post. A simple board that is on the screen, and a camera that is looking at it, I want to rotate the camera. For simplicity I am doing the entire camera in code. For context, per the other question and answer I have established that the board runs long on the Z axis, Shorter on the X axis, and the height is the Y axis.

Adding this code to the scene we can see my board running on the Z axis. I have raised the camera up on the Y axis a little to get a better view. My end goal is to get the board running longways accross the camera.

```
SCNNode *cameraNode = [SCNNode node];
cameraNode.camera = [SCNCamera camera];
cameraNode.camera.zFar = 200;
cameraNode.camera.zNear = 0.1;
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:cameraNode];
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 5, 0);
cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0);
```

Gives 
[image: Imgur]

Great start. Then I try to rotate the camera so it is looking from the top, down on the board. My understanding it that I would need to rotate around the X-axis to accomplish this. I did this by trying the following.

```
SCNNode *cameraNode = [SCNNode node];
cameraNode.camera = [SCNCamera camera];
cameraNode.camera.zFar = 200;
cameraNode.camera.zNear = 0.1;
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:cameraNode];
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 50, 0);
cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, -M_PI/2);
```

The iOS documentation states that the rotation in eulars is set with (z, y, x). This did not work, however, and only gave a blank screen. I then started experimenting and found that rotation around the Z axis would get me in the right direction.

```
SCNNode *cameraNode = [SCNNode node];
cameraNode.camera = [SCNCamera camera];
cameraNode.camera.zFar = 200;
cameraNode.camera.zNear = 0.1;
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:cameraNode];
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 50, 0);
cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(-M_PI/2, 0, 0);
```

This rendered this screen.
[image: Imgur]

This didn't make sense but I went ahead with it and eventually found that by also Rotating around the Y axis I could get my desired screen.

```
SCNNode *cameraNode = [SCNNode node];
cameraNode.camera = [SCNCamera camera];
cameraNode.camera.zFar = 200;
cameraNode.camera.zNear = 0.1;
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:cameraNode];
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 50, 0);
cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(-M_PI/2, -M_PI/2, 0);
```

The y rotation was also a little baffling because I would have expected to have to rotate around the Z axis.
[image: Imgur]

While this code works I have a similar question to my other post. Why do I have to rotate around the Z axis instead of the X axis for my first rotation. I think I might just not understand eular angles that well.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

as @mnuages pointed out, the documentation online states that this vector is in (x,y,z). This is contrary to the header documentation which I would normally use as can be seen here
[image: Imgur]

It would appear that this is just a bug/typo in Apple's code. Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Comment does not fit in a comment]*

Please note that the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNNode_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNNode/eulerAngles) states that

> The order of components in this vector matches the axes of rotation:
>
> - Pitch (the x component) is the rotation about the node’s x-axis.
> - Yaw (the y component) is the rotation about the node’s y-axis.
> - Roll (the z component) is the rotation about the node’s z-axis.

Comment: It would appear that we have encountered poor documentation. When looking at the header information (Which I normally use for my documentation, you can see that they clearly have this backwards. ![Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/LQMNg1c.png)

Comment: The next paragraph in the Apple docs says "SceneKit applies these rotations relative to the node’s pivot property in the reverse order of the components: first roll, then yaw, then pitch."  There is no inconsistency, it's just that the rotations are computed in reverse order.